# returning a list in a single line in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, return

I'm just curious if there is a simpler way to do this. If I want to print a list of items on one line I simply write

```
for i in things:
  print i,
```

but if I substitute print for return I'm obviously only going to get the first item of the list. I needed the list to comma and space separated as well so I ended up with a function that looks like this

```
def returner(things):
  thing = ""
  n = 1
  for i in things:
    thing += i
    if n < len(things):
      thing += ", "
    n += 1
  return thing
```

Was there a better way to do this?

Comment: Every time you do `thing +=` you are creating a new string. This is very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use join

```
return ", ".join([str(x) for x in things])
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. Guess I need to brush up on .join
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string join function -

```
",".join(things)
```

Comment: That's ok as long as `things` contains only strings.

Comment: yeah its just strings so looks like this works as well and a function was totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing identity with representation

```
def returner(things): #misnomer since this is actually a generator
    for itm in things:
        yield itm

print ", ".join(map(str,returner(a_list)))
```

Comment: `returner` seems unnecessary since you can just pass the list directly to `map`.